# What does "a weighing room" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, culture

The woman who said the following sentence is a waitress in a restaurant in a horserace course. Did she mean that the room is normally for kitchen use, like weighing  and preparing for food, and the working staff like her just  use this place as their own relaxing area? or does "a weighing room" mean something else?

here is the sentence:

‘I’m afraid the Weighing Room, our relaxed dining area, is being refurbished right now, but there are stalls along the stands where you can get something to eat.’

Comment: In this case, "relaxed" means casual, not formal dining area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the Weighing Room is the name of the area where guests dine, but that it's currently not available as it's being renovated. It's possible that, in years past, that room was used for weighing jockeys, but more likely it's just a name related to horse racing that seemed like a nice name for a dining hall at the race track.

Comment: I'm sure that 'weighing" is a racing term. It comes from the fact that every jockey is weighed before and after every race while carrying their saddle, etc. Every racecourse has a 'Weighing-in Room'. I suspect the restaurant was given its name simply because it is near that.

Comment: Google found this one: https://www.theoldweighingroom.co.uk/ (Doncaster, England). OP's profile doesn't show where s/he lives.

Comment: "the weighing room as a racing term " seems to make more sense now.